# What makes the spirit and body inseparable after the resurrection?

Tags: lds, nature-of-man, death, resurrection, resurrection-body

According to Mormon doctrine, body and spirit combined constitute a soul. Every man and woman that has ever lived on earth, previously lived as a spirit in the preexistence, and was born to earth into a mortal body prepared by mortal parents. Our mortal bodies are frail, and eventually die, at which point our spirits are separated from them until the resurrection.

I remember learning about body and spirit as a child, when our Sunday school teachers would explain that our bodies were like a glove, and our hands like our spirit. When the hand is in the glove it gives the glove life, but when we take it out, then the glove dies. After the resurrection, our spirits are reunited with our bodies, but cannot die again meaning that they are forever thereafter inseparable (see [Romans 6:9](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rom/6.9?lang=eng#8)).

According to Mormon Doctrine, What happens to our spirit and body during the resurrection that makes them inseparable?

Comment: I have a feeling that the answer to this question has something to do with blood and light... If it does, then how does light permanently *fuse* our spirits to our resurrected bodies?

Comment: The church doesn't focus on the "how" it works, just that is does. 2 Nephi 2:24 But behold, all things have been done in the wisdom of him who knoweth all things. - I don't consider this an answer, but this is from my experience. If someone knows otherwise, I am more than happy to learn!

Comment: I have a feeling the answer might be an Alma 37:11 question, but I'm hoping there may be some insight from the words of the brethren.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is not what you want to hear, but:

The separation of spirit and body is death. That means immortality implies that spirit and body will not be separated again. Resurrection makes us immortal.

This is the logic I would follow: Resurrection -> body immortal -> spirit & body inseparable
Instead of what seems to be your logic: Resurrection -> spirit & body inseparable -> body immortal

As to what makes us immortal: no clue

Answer (score 0):

We will have "new" bodies, which, not being made of earthly "flesh and blood", will be incorruptible. That is, they will not be subject to disease and deterioration, as mortal bodies are. Thus they cannot die—as these bodies are immortal, they cannot be separated from our spirit, because death is the only thing that can separate body and spirit. All this is explained by Alma. If I have more time later, I will find the relevant chapters/verses.